# How to subsetting pyspark dataframe in to 4 dataframes?

Tags: python, pyspark, data-science

I have a pyspark data frame with more than one million records, I need to subset in to 4 datafames. Like 1st 2.5 hundred thousand records in to one data frame and next 2.5 hundred thousand records in to next data frame. How can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best way is to do this via index column.
If You don't have one, simplest way is to create one on rdd using `.zipWithIndex()`

example:

```
data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).zipWithIndex()
```

Then let's create a DF:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, ['letters', 'id'])
```

calculate size:

```
size_of_df = df.count()/4
```

and create parts of df:

```
df_part0 = df.where(col('id') < size_of_df) 
df_part1 = df.where((col('id') > size_of_df) & 
                    (col('id') <= 2*size_of_df))
df_part2 = df.where((col('id') > 2*size_of_df) & 
                    (col('id') <= 3*size_of_df))
df_part3 = df.where((col('id') > 3*size_of_df) & 
                    (col('id') <= 4*size_of_df))
```